# Dual boot encryption

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, veracrypt

I want to encrypt my dual boot system. New installation (not installed now) of ubuntu with standard encryption and current windows system with veracrypt. My problem is that i can only create 4 primary partition and windows has 2 (100MB system + os) and ubuntu has 3 (root + swap + boot). So I want to ask you, should I try to move the system partition from windows to the os partition or to create the boot partition on another intern disk?

Answer (score 0):

You can create the `swap` in an extended partition and come around that 4 partition limit this way.

Answer (score 0):

While installing Ubuntu, install it all in one partition(or two: one for / and one for /home), and select the box that says `encrypt home folder`. You can then create a swapfile in the same partition. That way you will only use one(or two) more partitions.